# WCF and authentications requiring certificates?

Tags: wcf, certificate, wcf-security, x509certificate

Can anyone explain to me when a certifate is require using WCF and authentication. From my understanding although i could be way off :-)

basichttp doesn't require a certificate to do authentication is hosted in IIS and using SSL otherwise a certificate is required

All other bindings like netTcpBindings etc require the use of certficate - is this true?

Or does it depend on what type of authentication i am using?

I would really appreciate any info or maybe a table telling me when a certifcate is needed.

I have a number of scenerios i am investigating like hosting in IIS or hosting in WIndows Service..

And i just can't seem to find the info i need

THanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two scenarios where you need a certificate:

- A server side certificated that is used for SSL. For basichttpbinding, if you are sending a username and password over the network you should use SSL.
- A client side certificate if you are authenticating clients using certificates.

Other bindings may use machine keys and certificates in the operating system, but you do not need to install a certificate for them to work.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. SO i don't need to do a MakeCert. If i am using basicHTTP without SLL then i believe this is required, of course as you stated i should be using an SSL. What about using a custom username and password validator? over a transport other than basicHttp - i presume as you said thaen the bindings use there own internal certificates etc... So the only area where i see (i hope i am right) is when using basicHtttp without SLL and webHttp (REST Services) - This is about right?

Comment: SSL = Requires a certificate = need to run MakeCert

Comment: Yes exactly, so as i said the only cases where a MakeCert is "REquiered" would be basichttp and webHttp - basically the most simplest forms of binding that have no security etc

Comment: Yes, but only if you want to use SSL with these bindings